# Sprite-kit Main Character Picker

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I am using swift 2 and sprite-kit. I was wondering how I would make a choose character scene for my player to choose a character to play in the game, I have the scene set up, but I don't know how to integrate multiple characters, that can be chosen as the one to play? Any references or sample code would be appreciated.

in GameScene() i have

```
    //plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane")
    plane.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    plane.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 4)
    plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: plane.frame.height / 2)
    //plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: plane.texture!, size: plane.size)
    plane.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    plane.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    plane.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(plane)'
```

in settings() i have

```
    func mainScene(){

    mainSceenButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "mainMenu")
    mainSceenButton.size = CGSizeMake(200, 100)
    mainSceenButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + self.frame.height / 3)
    self.addChild(mainSceenButton)

    plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane")
    plane.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
    plane.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 + 100 )
    self.addChild(plane)

    plane1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane1")
    plane1.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
    plane1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 )
    self.addChild(plane1)

    plane2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane2")
    plane2.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50)
    plane2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - 100 )
    self.addChild(plane2)

}



override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    mainScene()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let mainMenuScene = StartScene(fileNamed: "StartScene")

    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if mainSceenButton.containsPoint(location){
            self.scene?.view?.presentScene(mainMenuScene!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0))
        }
        if plane1.containsPoint(location){
            GameScene().plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane1")
        } else {
            GameScene().plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane")
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet? This site isn't really meant for us to just write out sample code for you or make opinionated suggestions.

Comment: I updated my question @ZGski

Answer (score 0):

Really too broad of a question, but here's how I have seen this done in the past (and done myself)

1. Create a subclass of SKSpriteNode to make your custom player class.
2. When initializing change the texture of the node depending on what they select.

Comment: Ok so i updated my post what im trying to do in one view is click on a plane and then have that plane be the image in another view, but its not working

Comment: @ShaneReichenfeld Looks like you might need to learn a little more about OOP and Swift... You shouldn't be initializing the new scene by doing GameScene().plane... I am actually very confused as to what you are doing. You should post the entire class. I don't see where you present the scene or anything.

Comment: @Kendel the OP needs to know that when a new GameScene is created, all fields will be initialized to empty / default values. OP seems to think that `GameScene().plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane1")` is permanently setting the plane on GameScene.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using NSUserDefaults to save the users selection in Settings touchesBegan.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if plane.containsPoint(location) {
    defaults.setObject("plane", forKey: "userPlane")
} else if plane1.containsPoint(location) {
    defaults.setObject("plane1", forKey: "userPlane")
} else if plane2.containsPoint(location) {
    defaults.setObject("plane2", forKey: "userPlane")
}
```

Then in GameScene, retrieve the selection when creating the plane.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let userPlane = defaults.stringForKey("userPlane") {
    plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: userPlane)
}
```

In your code you are trying to set the plane on a new instance of GameScene, but that selection will be lost as soon as you exit the settings scene.