# Changeable Image

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

```
    Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost1")
    Ghost.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    Ghost.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - Ghost.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 2)

    Ghost.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Ghost.frame.height / 1.4)
    Ghost.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ghost
    Ghost.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall
    Ghost.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall | PhysicsCatagory.Score
    Ghost.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Ghost.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    Ghost.zPosition = 2


    self.addChild(Ghost)
```

On my app i have an object that moves around on the screen and it name is "ghost". I am not sure how to set up a button that would change the code to say

```
Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost2")
```

instead of

```
Ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the image for an SKSpriteNode you assign a different texture:

```
Ghost.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Ghost2")
```

Note: You should use lower case letters for variable names to distinquish them from class names.

An example implementation that includes a Button and your Ghost would be like below with a red button created in the top right corner. See that the declaration of the button and the ghost now occurs outside of didMoveToView, so that these variables can be referenced later, when the user taps the screen.

```
class ButtonGhostScene: SKScene {
    var button: SKNode! = nil
    var ghost: SKSpriteNode! = nil

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        button = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 44))
        button.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width, y:self.size.height)

        ghost = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ghost1")
        ghost.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        ghost.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2 - Ghost.frame.width, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        ghost.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Ghost.frame.height / 1.4)
        ghost.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ghost
        ghost.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall
        ghost.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall | PhysicsCatagory.Score
        ghost.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ghost.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        ghost.zPosition = 2

        self.addChild(ghost)
        self.addChild(button)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Loop over all the touches in this event
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            // Get the location of the touch in this scene
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            // Check if the location of the touch is within the button's bounds
            if button.containsPoint(location) {
                ghost.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Ghost2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user taps the screen, touchesBegan is executed and a check is made to see if the users tap is on the button.

Comment: Don't know who down voted you, but this is definitely an answer,  I would just talk more about the button process since that is what the question is asking

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I initially focused on the `SKTexture` and not the Button, then improved the answer after the down vote!

Comment: yes I know,  that's why I said talk more about the button

Comment: I am having a problem with this line of code, let location = touch.locationInNode(self) When added in your code, i got an error that said replace "loactionInNode" with "location" and one i clicked on that i got an error that "Cannot invoke 'location' with an argument list of type '(GameScene)'

Comment: @OrenEdrich Change it to `touch.location` without the argument.

Comment: What should I change to "touch.loaction"?

Comment: Now i get an error that says "Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat?' to expected argument type 'CGPoint'

Comment: @OrenEdrich I update the example again, should be `let location = touch.location(in: self)`. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I don't have any errors now, but i cannot get the button to show up, any thoughts?

Comment: @OrenEdrich The button might be off screen, you could try giving it the same position as your ghost i.e. Centre screen, then adjust it slightly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124170/discussion-between-oren-edrich-and-mark-brownsword).

Comment: If you are able to help me with a few more questions I will give you credits on the description of the app. When the "ghost" dies and you click the "restart" button the "ghost" goes back to the original image. What code would I use to have the app remember the texture of the ghost?

Comment: You could try`NSUserDefaults` similar to my answer to this [Stack Overflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231990/sprite-kit-main-character-picker/39260107#39260107). No credit required! BTW, this is probably a new question.